# Applications for the degenerate case of $x^x$ in the unit range

Tags: number-theory

Does there exist an application that makes use of the degenerate case of $x^x$ in the unit range?

For most of the function $x^x$ the y value's progression as $x$ increases or decreases makes sense.  But within the unit range (specifically at the extrema 0.3679...) something non-intuitive occurs. I find this inherently interesting but I've been challenged to provide an application for the phenomenon.

Are there any?

[image: degenerate case of x^x]

Comment: That minimum is at $x=1/e$.

Comment: Why would that be non-intuitive? $\lim_{x\to0+}x^x=1^1=1$, and $0.25^{0.25}=0.5^{0.5}$, so I'd *expect* a minimum of the function $f(x)=x^x$ between those values. The derivative is $(1+\ln x)\,x^x$, so it's clearly decreasing for $x<1/e$.

Comment: I've deleted some comments. Please keep interactions civil and avoid long exchanges that are not relevant to the post at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Gerrys hint, it seems as if my question relates to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707570/what-are-the-uses-of-eulers-number-e) `What Are The Uses of Eulers Number` in which real world examples of actual applications are given.

Thanks to Gerry and @TheBluegrassMathmatician for answering this one.